# how to get browser window resolution while loading Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Really need your input. I have unity furniture configurator and client decided he wants make it fully adjustable depending on browser window. Would be perfect if unity can get resolution while loading.

I found this http://helloracer.com/unity/ - it is exactly same thing i need.

I cannot figure out how to achieve this result

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Having in mind you tagged your question with php - you can not do that using it. You need to do it with javascript:

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```

and somehow transfer it to your php code, which later decides what to do based on that. You can achieve it using 2 http calls in the same page.